# Django: My template is not loading/being called

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Edit: as @HåkenLid said, I should've asked this as 2 separate posts, the first question (regarding the template) has been answered!

I'm new to Django and I've been having a nice time with it so far. I'm trying to build a blog for fun but I've run with the some problems.

Here are my models, forms, urls, views and file tree:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtzF7.png

For the first problem: (To save space I've only added parts of each file)

```
#blog/views.py
class BlogDetail(generic.DetailView):
model = Entry
template_name = "blog/entry_detail.html"


#blog/templates/blog/entry_detail.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load django_markdown %}

<div class="post">
  <h2><a href="{% url "entry_detail" slug=object.slug %}">{{ object.title }}</a></h2>
  <p class="meta">
    {{ object.creation_date }} |
    Tagged under {{  object.tags.all|join:", " }}
  </p>
  {{ object.body|markdown }}
</div>


#blog/urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', views.BlogIndex.as_view(), name="index"),
    url(r'^entry/(?P<slug>\S+)$', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name="entry_detail"),
)


#blog/models.py
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    publication_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, null=True)
    modification_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)

    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    objects = EntryQuerySet.as_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.publication_date <= now

    def is_published(self):
        return self.publication_date is not False

    is_published.boolean = True
    is_published.short_description = 'Is it Published?'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("entry_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta():
        verbose_name = "Blog Entry"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Entries"
        ordering = ['-creation_date']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ On save, update timestamps """
        if not self.id:
            self.creation_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.modification_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        return super(Entry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I enter something like

> localhost:8000/entry/this-is-an-entry-title-slug

e.j: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlItb.png

I don't get the detail of the entry, just the title defined in base.html and that kind of stuff, I really don't know why it isn't being loaded.

As always, thank you very much for your help, and sorry if this are very basic questions but I haven't been able to find any solutions so far.

Comment: It's better to ask each question as a separate post, since they don't seem to be related.

Comment: "I don't get the detail of the entry, just the title defined in base.html and that kind of stuff" 

Can you explain what shows up? This is quite unclear.

Comment: @HåkenLid I didn't want to spam too much, I thought that since they are on the same project / using the same framework it was OK to ask them together.
I meant to say that I should see the contents of entry_detail.html, the title, creation_date, tags and body of that specific Entry. I'm uploading a screenshot right now.
Edit: Here is the where the entry_detail should be rendered: http://i.imgur.com/c7yir79.png

Comment: Are you sure that blogs.urls are included in the project's main urls.py?

Comment: I think so, like this?
    urlpatterns = patterns(
        '',
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^markdown/', include('django_markdown.urls')),
        url(r'^', include('blog.urls')),
    )

Comment: You can edit the question and cut-paste the modelforms question into a new thread. It's less likely that you'll get new answers here, since this question has been marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When extending templates you need to use {% block %}

If you have a block called 'content' in base.html, you can do this:

```
#blog/templates/blog/entry_detail.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load django_markdown %}
{% block content %}
<div class="post">
  <h2><a href="{% url "entry_detail" slug=object.slug %}">{{ object.title }}</a></h2>
  <p class="meta">
    {{ object.creation_date }} |
    Tagged under {{  object.tags.all|join:", " }}
  </p>
  {{ object.body|markdown }}
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Thank you, do I always need blocks? I'll investigate further on templates.

Comment: Extends and block work together. If you don't put content in child templates inside a block, it's impossible for django to know where it's supposed to fit in the parent template.

Answer (score 1):

For part 1, I think the issue is with your regex:

```
r'^entry/(?P<slug>\S+)$
```

Should be:

```
r'^entry/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/'
```

Since your current pattern isn't capturing the slug, it's not being loaded into the context.

I am not much help on part 2, sorry. If you were doing this in your own view you could override the `form_valid` method of the CBV, but I am not sure how to accomplish the same within the built-in admin panel.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that I omitted `entry/` from the second pattern. Try the edited pattern - does that work?

Comment: Yep, I had tried before posting the comment, I believe it is not a problem with the regex (at least right now)

Comment: Just for testing, what happens if you replace the `slug` in your URL pattern with `pk`? A `DetailView` fetches the object for display by looking in the URL for one of those two things. If it works with a PK but not a slug, there may be an issue with the way your slugs are getting saved or something like that.

Comment: I replaced slug for pk first in my browsers URL, 404 No Blog Entry found matching the query.
Then I replaced slug for pk in the regex and the templates and it works exactly like the slug, just with an id for each entry instead of a slug.